# Move an Object in the direction it is facing? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, move

There are questions like this but I couldn't find any answers in C#, so here's my question: I want to rotate an object (in Unity 5) in the direction it's facing. I currently have this code to rotate my player.

```
using UnityEngine;                                                       
using System.Collections;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isLeft = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (isLeft == false)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 45,0);
                isLeft = true;
                Debug.Log("Turned Right");
            }
            else
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, -45, 0);
                Debug.Log("Turned Left");
                isLeft = false;
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: The title says **"Move an Object in the direction it is facing"** then the body of your question is saying **"I want to rotate an object (in Unity 5) in the direction it's facing"**....To move and to rotate an object is not the-same thing. Which one are your really trying to do? On the other hand, does the code in your question work? What's happening with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your question and description are a bit ambiguous, it seems that you want to move the arrow, in the direction it's facing, correct?

Make sure that the arrow in the game object, is pointing forwards. You can see what forward is, by selecting the game object in the scene. Forward will be the blue arrow.

Now in code, to move it in this direction, you can move it in many different ways. Apply force/Translate/Set position. I recommend you try them out, to see what looks and feels the best. To simply change its position:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
```

Where movement speed is a float that describes how fast it should move. Time.deltaTime is necessary if you put this code in Update().

Answer (score 0):

Ok full edit on answer, so you have an arrow and whichever way its facing you want it to move the direction it's facing and when the player clicks it have it turn 45 degrees.

the easy part is turning it, basically you would call an onclick() function or set up colliders on the object and write up a brief snippet checking when mouse click down does it equal your arrow.name or collider.  if so set up a new variable for a Vector3 to store the new rotation and just add 45 to the objects rotation and set the new rotation of the gameobject equal to your new rotation variable.

Comment: Here:   http://imgur.com/pf8fVBk                                                                       [img]http://i.imgur.com/pf8fVBk.png[/img]   I want it to move forward in the direction the arrow is facing, and when the player clicks to rotate it 45 degrees, for it to go the new way it's facing.